# Minimize function of x

Tags: mathematical-optimization, binary-search

I have a function I need to minimize,

[image: Function]

where x1,y1,x2,y2,v2,v1 are given to me. I have to find the global minima of this function for any x.

I figured out that the global minima of the function will be for x between min(x1,x2) and max(x1,x2) and the function between the range should be U-shaped curve. So, taking low=min(x1,x2) and high=max(x1,x2), I did a binary search where I took an efficiency parameter e=0.000001 and gave the following condition in the binary search

if(f(mid+e) < f(mid))
    high=mid-e;
else
    low=mid+e;

But, I am not getting correct results for this. I am looking for an accuracy of 6-7 decimal places. Any help in form of code/pseudo-code would be appreciated.

Comment: Format your question (not nice to read). Show your code and explain a bit more what you are doing and what you are observing. What does ```But, I am not getting correct results for this``` mean? What kind of precision do you need? Which programming-language?

Comment: I made a few changes. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: You still did not explain what's wrong with your results and you also did not show any code or told us about the programming language. Normally one would use a classic optimization algorithm which is implemented in some library. So showing you some code within python/scipy might not help you.

Comment: I am not getting the acccuracy( 6-7 decimal places) I need. Any language is fine. Even psuedo-code is fine.

Comment: Local-optimal or global-optimal solution? It seems non-convex which is a problem regarding global solutions.

Comment: Global optimal solution.

Comment: Can you give examples of the constants (x1 etc)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks non-convex which is a problem in general as nonconvex optimization is very hard. Especially combined with the desire for high-accuracy solutions. In general it's not feasible (to find any global minimum), but with such a small problem there is a chance (but the accuracy might still be a problem).

The following code (python + scipy + pyomo + couenne) is just some demonstration of some possible approaches. The best approach of course will use some characteristics of the function.

- [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/): open-source general scientific function library
- [pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/): open-source linear/nonlinear mathematical programming library
- [couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne): open-source global MINLP solver

The general idea is:

- Use well-tested scalar minimization algorithms like [brent's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method) to solve your problem

  - This might be enough for you (but a global solution is not guaranteed)
  - Should be available in most languages
- Compare with an nonconvex/nonlinear MINLP approach using the solver couenne

  - Look up couenne's docs to get an idea what's going on
- Just for fun: use couenne's solution and try to polish it

  - Use the above scalar minimization methods (this time: the more conservatife/safe methods `golden` and `bounded`; `brentq` uses some heavy trick to speed up convergency) with couenne's global minimum as bounds (and widen by some small constant eps)

#### Code

```python
from __future__ import division
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar, brute
import math

""" Constants """
x1 =3
x2 = 1
y1 = 0.5
y2 = 3
v1 = 2
v2 = 2

""" Scipy-based 1d-minimization using brentq (local-optimal) """
def f(x):
    return math.sqrt(x**2 - 2*x1*x + x1**2 + y1**2) / v1 + \
           math.sqrt(x**2 - 2*x2*x + x2**2 + y2**2) / v2
res = minimize_scalar(f)
print('Brentq: ', res.x)


""" Pyomo + Couenne based minimization (global-optimal) """
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = Var()
model.obj = Objective(expr=sqrt(model.x**2 - 2*x1*model.x + x1**2 + y1**2) / v1 + \
                           sqrt(model.x**2 - 2*x2*model.x + x2**2 + y2**2) / v2, sense=minimize)

opt = SolverFactory('couenne')
results = opt.solve(model)
print('Couenne: ', model.x.value)

""" Reopt 1d-minimization ("golden" + "bounded") with obtained bounds by couenne """
eps = 0.001
res = minimize_scalar(f, method='bounded', bounds=(model.x.value - eps, model.x.value + eps),
                         options={'xatol': 1e-9, 'maxiter': 1000})
print('Couenne reopt (bounded): ', res.x)

res = minimize_scalar(f, method='golden', bounds=(model.x.value - eps, model.x.value + eps),
                         options={'xtol': 1e-9})
print('Couenne reopt (golden): ', res.x)
```

#### Output

```
Brentq: 
2.71428567406
f(x)
2.01556443707

Couenne: 
2.71428571429
f(x)
2.01556443707

Couenne reopt (bounded): 
2.71428573487
f(x)
2.01556443707

Couenne reopt (golden): 
2.71428570645
f(x)
2.01556443707
```

The performance of these optimizers might depend heavily on the chosen constants of your problem. You have to decide which route to go. I don't know which language you are using and which libraries are available.